# Best approach to fetch data from wp options to js file or php file

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, javascript

I am creating my first ever plugin, as I am not a programmer, I have been following tutorials and reading the codex, etc.

My plugin consist in showing a notice to users when certain conditions are met, I have written it in jQuery and placed it in a js file which is enqueued by the plugin along with styles.

I have followed a tutorial that simply ads a settings page and a form with a simple text box to save data in the wp options table, I tested and it worked, the data was stored successfully.

How do I now transfer the data from the wp options to my js file, the line where the notice is display is;

```
jQuery('.notice_container').wrap(<'div id="custom_notice"><span>Hello World....</span></div>')
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not using AJAX for form submission, you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Here's a simplified version:

In your plugin file:

```
function wpse105919_add_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'myjs', plugins_url( '/myjs.js', __FILE__ ) );
  wp_localize_script( 'myjs', 'jsLocalizedObject', 'hello world');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse105919_add_scripts');
```

contents of `myjs.js` file:

```
alert( jsLocalizedObject );
```

[`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) will add a global variable called `jsLocalizedObject` to your document's `<head>`. IF you view the source of your page, you'll see something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var jsLocalizedObject = "hello world";
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

To get a value from your `wp_options` table, you can use [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) and then pass the result instead of the `hello world` in the `wp_localize_script` function.

Your code would then look like:

```
function wpse105919_add_scripts(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'myjs', plugins_url( '/myjs.js', __FILE__ ) );
  $myoption = get_option('option_name', 'default_value');
  wp_localize_script( 'myjs', 'jsLocalizedObject', $myoption);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse105919_add_scripts');
```

and your jQuery part:

```
jQuery('.notice_container').wrap(<'div id="custom_notice"><span>' + jsLocalizedObject + '</span></div>')
```

Note that you should use [`admin_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) instead if your JS should load in the dashboard.